# string/text storage limits in a sqlite3 database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have a note field of string type in one of my models in my sqlite3 database, but I realized that I needed to store more text than string would allow.

I just ran a migration changing the type of the field from string to text. Looking at my database, it says that the type is now `text(255)`, whereas before it was `varchar(255)`.

What does the 255 mean? Is that a character limit? If so, would I have the same storage problems as before? How would I fix this?

Here is the migration I used to change the field type

```
change_column(:posts, :note, :text)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQLite does not enforce text storage limits. If you declare a column VARCHAR(1) or TEXT(1) you still can store some very long blob of 500 Megabytes inside it. Even though that is not adviseable.

```
~$ sqlite
SQLite version 3.7.2
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table foo ( bar text(3));
sqlite> insert into foo values ('aeiou');
sqlite> select * from foo;
aeiou
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just make your storage type `text` and not put any limit on it. The 255 denotes the maximum number of characters allowed in the field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I do this? The migration I ran to change the type was change_column(:posts, :note, :text), so I didn't specify 255 myself.

Comment: @ben - I'm not sure, perhaps try a `change_table` call, and do `:limit => nil`. Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#changing-tables